# Video in WebView plays only sound

Tags: android, android-webview, android-video-player

I have the following problem: I am using `WebView` to display some content in my app. Sometimes there is a video which is embedded into the content which is presented in this `WebView`. The problem is that after clicking "play", the video starts, but no image is visible - only sound is being played. Before starting the video - correct thumbnail is shown. In the LogCat I see following error messages:

```
06-26 16:51:21.449  25222-25222/com.package.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ native_setup
06-26 16:51:21.449  25222-25222/com.package.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ constructor
06-26 16:51:21.459  25222-25222/com.package.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
06-26 16:51:21.459  25222-25222/com.package.app I/MediaPlayer﹕ path is null
06-26 16:51:21.479  25222-25222/com.package.app D/MediaPlayer﹕ setDataSource IOException happend :
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://example.com/linktovideo.mp4
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1052)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:907)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:834)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:987)
            at com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerBridge.setDataSource(MediaPlayerBridge.java:117)
            at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
            at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 16:51:21.479  25222-25222/com.package.app D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

The same video is displayed correctly in the Chrome for Android web browser.

Code I use to display my `WebView`:

```
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.details_web_view);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
```

CustomWebViewClient:

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
                getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                AnalyticsHandler.sendAction(getActivity(), AnalyticsHandler.ACTION_CLICKED_ON_URL_IN_ARTICLE, url);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

add this code into your webview

```
WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Does Javascript has anything to do with displaying a mp4 video?

Comment: Still only sound-no image after adding this line.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```